# Remove uploaded profile picture and reset to default image in laravel issue

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-update, laravel-6

I have a user update form with a user photo. Currently I'm saving my user photo (file name) in my user table's propic column.

**The Problem**

I'm trying to add a remove photo button when a user wants to remove the uploaded image. Once the user click the remove photo button user's propic column value need to be reset to default value (user-photo.png). And I need to display that remove photo button only for the users who have updated their profile photos. Users with default profile photo doesn't need the option.

**What I have done so far**

This is my form, in user blade

```
<form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row mt-5">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img src="/propics/{{$user->propic}}" alt="Profile Pic" id="profile_pic_display" class="mb-3">
                    <input type="file" name="propic" class="form-control"> 
                    @error('propic')
                    <span class="help-block" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                <!-- <form action="{{ route('settings.update',$user->id) }}" method="POST"> -->
                    @csrf
                    @method('PUT')
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group field-user-firstname required">
                                <label class="control-label"
                                       for="user-firstname">{{ __('sentence.First Name') }}</label>
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                                       name="name" value="{{$user->name}}" autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group field-user-lastname required">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user-lastname">{{ __('sentence.Last Name') }}</label>
                                <input id="last_name" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name"
                                       value="{{$user->last_name}}" autocomplete="last_name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group field-user-mobile required">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user-mobile">{{ __('sentence.Mobile') }}</label><br/>
                                <input id="mobile_1" type="tel"
                                       class="form-control @error('mobile') is-invalid @enderror" name="mobile"
                                       value="{{$user->mobile}}" style="min-width:398px;" autocomplete="mobile"
                                       autofocus>

                                @error('mobile')
                                <span class="help-block" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group field-user-email required">
                                <label class="control-label" for="user-email">{{ __('sentence.Email') }}</label>
                                <input id="email_" type="email"
                                       class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email"
                                       value="{{$user->email}}" autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                                <button type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-default">{{ __('sentence.Cancel') }}</button>
                                <button type="submit"
                                        class="btn btn-default subscribe px-5">{{ __('sentence.Update') }}</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

        </form>
```

And following is my controller (Only the update function is included)

```
public function update(Request $request, User $setting)
        {

            $changedAttributes = array_diff($request->all(), $setting->getAttributes());

            $validationRules = array_intersect_key([
               'name'      => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
               'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:5', 'max:255'],
               'mobile'    => ['required', 'numeric','min:9','regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
               2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
               4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
               'email'     => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
               'propic' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048'],
           ], $changedAttributes);

           if($request->hasFile('propic'))
           {
                $this->validate($request, [
                    'name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:2', 'max:255'],
                    'last_name' => ['required', 'alpha','min:5', 'max:255'],
                    'mobile' => ['required', 'numeric','min:9','regex:/\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|3[70]|7|1)\d{1,14}$/'],
                    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users,email,'.$setting->id.''],
                    'propic' => ['required','image','mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg','max:2048'],
                ],$request->all());

                $imageName = time().'.'.$request->propic->extension();  
                $request->propic->move(public_path('propics'), $imageName);
                $setting->propic=$imageName;
                $setting->name=$request->input('name');
                $setting->last_name=$request->input('last_name');
                $setting->mobile=$request->input('mobile');
                $setting->email=$request->input('email');
                $setting->update();
                return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('sentence.User updated successfully'));  
           }

           $this->validate($request, $validationRules);

           $setting->update($changedAttributes);

           return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('sentence.User updated successfully'));  

        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check in your view if user profile photo is not "user-photo.png" and if true insert a button to reset photo:

```
@if($user->propic != 'user-photo.png')
    <button type="submit" name="resetphoto" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Profile Pic</button>
@endif
```

Then in your controller at the beginning of update() method check if the user has clicked on "Reset Profile Pic" button, and then if is true set the column back to default value, then save the model

```
if ($request->has('resetphoto')){
    $setting->propic = 'user-photo.png';
    $setting->update();
    return Redirect::back()->with('success',__('sentence.User profile pic reset successfully'));
}
```

PS: Im assuming your "$setting" is the User model